# MockServer setup for HTTPS SSL requests

Tags: ssl, https, mockserver

Maybe someone can share a working setup for mocking https requests. All my experiments ended with catching of encrypted requests.

The documentation is not really clear and I hope there is a way to record and mock the requests in decrypted form.

Comment: I would also be very happy if there was a better explanation.